# Inserting blob file with tsql but source file is only on client machine not at the server side?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to put a file as a blob in to my database. The file is not on the sql server side, but only on my client from where i start the sql skripts.

If I try to open the file like this

```
select * from openrowset(BULK, 'E:\Installer\metadata.hwr.de.xml',SINGLE_BLOB) a,
```

I receive the error

```
Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot bulk load because the file "E:\Installer\metadata.hwr.de.xml"
could not be opened.  Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
```

Only when I add the file to the server, it will work. Is there a possibility to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: The code runs on the server so any local paths must also be on the server, you could load over a unc share?

Answer (score 0):

you can share your folder and server can access it

```
select * from openrowset(BULK, '\\developermchine1\shared\metadata.hwr.de.xml',SINGLE_BLOB) a
```